# Generate HMAC SHA256 hash using key in C++

Tags: c++, sha256, hmac

I am looking for some function or a way that would return HMAC SHA256 hash in C++ using secret key. I have seen documentation of Crypto++ and OpenSSL but it does not accept an extra parameter of secret key for computation. Can someone help me by providing some info, code snippets or links.

Comment: HMACs by definition have a key input as well as a data input. provide a link to the HMAC you are having trouble with. See [HMAC definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition). HMACs use a hash function so you will see some form of name joining.

Comment: I removed the OpenSSL and Crypto++ tags. You should add the tags when you are using the technology; and not for something like "What should I use and how should I do it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL docs for [HMAC](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/HMAC_CTX_init.html), clearly state the requirement of a 'key' as part of context initialization.

```
int HMAC_Init_ex(HMAC_CTX *ctx, const void *key, int key_len,
               const EVP_MD *md, ENGINE *impl);
```

> HMAC() computes the message authentication code of the n bytes at d
>   using the hash function evp_md and the key **key** which is key_len bytes
>   long.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [POCO library](https://pocoproject.org/)

Sample code:

```
class SHA256Engine : public Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine
{
public:
    enum
    {
        BLOCK_SIZE = 64,
        DIGEST_SIZE = 32
    };

    SHA256Engine()
            : DigestEngine("SHA256")
    {
    }

};


Poco::HMACEngine<SHA256Engine> hmac{secretKey};
hmac.update(string);

std::cout << "HMACE hex:" << Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex(hmac.digest()) << std::endl;// lookout difest() calls reset ;)
```

## Sample integration with POCO using cmake install:

```
mkdir build_poco/
cd build_poco/ && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install ../poco/
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.8)
PROJECT(SamplePoco)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

SET(SOURCE_FILES
        src/main.cpp
        )

SET(_IMPORT_PREFIX lib/build_poco/install)

INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoFoundationTargets.cmake)
INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoNetTargets.cmake)
INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoJSONTargets.cmake)
INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoXMLTargets.cmake)
INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoCryptoTargets.cmake)
INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoUtilTargets.cmake)
INCLUDE(lib/build_poco/install/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoNetSSLTargets.cmake)


ADD_EXECUTABLE(SamplePoco ${SOURCE_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SamplePoco
        Poco::Foundation
        Poco::Crypto
        Poco::Util
        Poco::JSON
        Poco::NetSSL
        )
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SamplePoco PUBLIC src/)
```

Sample implementation used here: https://github.com/gelldur/abucoins-api-cpp

Answer (score 6):

For consistency, following is a sample of function to generate SHA256-HMAC using OpenSSL

```cpp
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

std::string CalcHmacSHA256(std::string_view decodedKey, std::string_view msg)
{
    std::array<unsigned char, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE> hash;
    unsigned int hashLen;

    HMAC(
        EVP_sha256(),
        decodedKey.data(),
        static_cast<int>(decodedKey.size()),
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(msg.data()),
        static_cast<int>(msg.size()),
        hash.data(),
        &hashLen
    );

    return std::string{reinterpret_cast<char const*>(hash.data()), hashLen};
}
```

For the record, I like Crypto++ better as in case of Crypto++ generated binary is smaller. The drawback is that Crypto++ does not have a CMake module.

Comment: On MacOS, I am getting error: _Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64_, "_EVP_sha256", "_HMAC", referenced from ...

Comment: @VincentGuyard Did you pass `-lssl -lcrypto` keys to g++?

Comment: I could deal with this adding theses lines in my CMakeLists.txt: _include_directories(/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include)_

_target_link_libraries(fillerchecker /usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/libcrypto.a)_

Comment: In order to use openssl in the CMake project, you should use `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)` and then `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${PROJECT_NAME} OpenSSL::Crypto)`

Answer (score 4):

Following is a sample of function to generate SHA256-HMAC using Crypto++

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::HashFilter;

#include <cryptopp/hmac.h>
using CryptoPP::HMAC;

#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
using CryptoPP::SHA256;

std::string CalcHmacSHA256(std::string_view decodedSecretKey, std::string_view request)
{
    // Calculate HMAC
    HMAC<SHA256> hmac(reinterpret_cast<CryptoPP::byte const*>(decodedSecretKey.data()), decodedSecretKey.size());

    std::string calculated_hmac;
    auto sink = std::make_unique<StringSink>(calculated_hmac);

    auto filter = std::make_unique<HashFilter>(hmac, sink.get());
    sink.release();

    StringSource(reinterpret_cast<CryptoPP::byte const*>(request.data()), request.size(), true, filter.get()); // StringSource
    filter.release();

    return calculated_hmac;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << CalcHmacSHA256("key", "data");
}
```

The source is [CME iLink2 specification](https://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Session+Layer+-+Logon)

Comment: The page you link to doesn't seem to use `make_unique`

Comment: Once `HashFilter` object is created I call `std::unique_ptr::release` member function to release ownership from `unique_ptr` to `HashFilter`.

Comment: Right, the CME version of this function does not use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: OK, that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

I had to modify @DmytroOvdiienko's answer a bit to get hexadecimal output:

```
#include <iomanip>

...

std::string CalcHmacSHA256(std::string_view decodedKey, std::string_view msg)
{
    std::array<unsigned char, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE> hash;
    unsigned int hashLen;
    HMAC(
        EVP_sha256(),
        decodedKey.data(),
        static_cast<int>(decodedKey.size()),
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(msg.data()),
        static_cast<int>(msg.size()),
        hash.data(),
        &hashLen
    );
    std::stringstream out;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < hashLen; i++) {
        out << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::right << std::hex << (int)hash.data()[i];
    }
    return out.str();
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::string key = "ESiFg448MqOmhQyxbt6HEHHPnAA1OE8nX0o9ANIVMIvWLISQS0MivDrkZvnBxMEI";
    std::string msg = "foo";
    std::string_view key_view{key};
    std::string_view msg_view{msg};
    std::cout << CalcHmacSHA256(key_view, msg_view) << std::endl;
}
```

The `<iomanip>`, `setfill`, `setw`, `right` are needed to make sure single-digit hex values are prefixed with a 0. An alternative is to use boost:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

...

        out << boost::format("%02x") % (int)hash.data()[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cpp-cryptlite](https://github.com/lyokato/cpp-cryptlite) to generate HMAC SHA256 hash, Following is the code snippet:

```
std::string src_str = "abcdefg";
std::string secret_key = "xxxxxx";  // this value is an example
boost::uint8_t digest[32];  // cryptlite::sha256::HASH_SIZE
cryptlite::hmac<cryptlite::sha256>::calc(src_str, secret_key, digest);
// and digest is the output hash
```

Comment: It depends on boost library. It is neither good nor bad. Just it is.